# How to autorelease CGColorRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a method that returns CGColorRef instance created by CGColorCreate method. I need to autorelease the color return from this method. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
//red,green,blue are from 0-255 range

+(CGColorRef) getColorFromRed:(int)red Green:(int)green Blue:(int)blue Alpha:(int)alpha
{
    CGFloat r = (CGFloat) red/255.0;
    CGFloat g = (CGFloat) green/255.0;
    CGFloat b = (CGFloat) blue/255.0;
    CGFloat a = (CGFloat) alpha/255.0;  
    CGFloat components[4] = {r,g,b,a};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //CGColorRelease(color);
    // I need to auto release the color before returning from this.

    return color;
}
```

Comment: Pedantic: One should only name a method starting with `get` if it takes to-be-filled-in pointers as arguments. A better name here would be `+ (CGColorRef)CGColorWithRed:(int)red green:(int)green blue:(int)blue alpha:(int)alpha` (following the lead of the `NSColor`/`UIColor` methods).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot directly, as mvds said. Also `UIColor` and `CGColorRef` are *not* tool-free bridged -- why the converter functions then?  However (and while **I don't recommend** it -- use `UIColor` instead!) there is a trick to do so:

Create a **autoreleased** UIColor object and return it's CGColor. Like so:

```
return [UIColor colorWith... ].CGColor;
```

This will return a regular `CGColorRef` object that is bound to it's `UIColor`. Which means that if the `UIColor` is released in the autorelease loop, it's `CGColorRef` will be released as well -- unless it has been retained somewhere else using a `CGRetain(...)`, which the caller of your method should have done if it wanted to keep the color. As such the `CGColorRef` is pseudo-autoreleased...

Still: I would **not** recommend doing so. Use UIColor directly!

Comment: Although I must admit this is quite ingenious, it introduces (chances for) bugs that are almost impossible to find in your own code 6 months from now.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
CGColorRef color = (CGColorRef)[(id)CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components) autorelease];
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Autorelease pools work on objects listening to the `release` message, and a `CGColorRef` is not such an object.

You could rewrite things to return a `UIColor`, by doing

```
UIColor *ret = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:color]; // ret will be autoreleased
CGColorRelease(color);
return ret;
```

Comment: In a Cocoa program, a CGColorRef is a Cocoa object that implements the NSObject protocol.  It is perfectly safe to put one in an autorelease pool.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Do you have a pointer to documentation supporting this?

Answer (score -3):

Use toll-free bridge:

```
return [(UIColor *)color autorelease];
```

Or you can user `+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha` method and then do `return [myColor CGColor];`

Comment: UIColor and CGColorRef are not documented to be toll-free bridged.  You can use +colorWithCGColor: to convert to a UIColor though.